# Closure of the graphic of the vector of the players' payoff functions

Tags: game-theory

Let $X_i$ be a compact subset of a topological vector space (not necessarily Hausdorff) , $i=1,\ldots,N$,
$ \ u_i: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the payoff functions and $u$ the vector of the players' payoff functions.

Is true that the closure of the graphic of $u$ is a subset of $X\times \mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: It's the *graph*, not *graphic*. And yes.

Comment: I'm sorry because of that. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: This is pretty much a direct consequence of the definition of the graph of a function, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function

Comment: But $\overline{Gr(u)} \subseteq \overline{X\times \mathbb{R}^N} = \overline{X}\times \mathbb{R}^N$ and $X$ is not necessarily closed.

Comment: $X$ is compact as the Cartesian product of compact spaces.

Comment: Is true that the closure of compact is compact in t.v.s? That is not true in a general topological space.

Comment: I see, you are right. I overlooked that you allow for non-Hausdorff spaces. Of course if the closure of $X$ is larger than $X$, this cannot hold.

Comment: A TVS is Hausdorff iff every singleton is closed. Since every singleton is compact, you get trivial counterexamples whenever the TVS is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that I need to suppose it to the concept of reciprocally upper semicontinuous.